# How to create response page and add url in cybersource redirect url so I could get response parameters on my page?

Tags: redirect, response, payment-gateway, cybersource

I'm doing form post with request parameters on cybersource. Which lands me on cybersource payment form. I'm able to do payments, on receipt page it has a button where we can setup our application page url. On that page I want to pass the response details and save it in database. How can I capture response field from receipt page.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a Merchant Notifications URL in your Secure Acceptance Profile so CyberSource sends you updates on transaction results which you can parse and store in your database.

You can follow these steps to set up merchant notifications:

Configuring Merchant Notifications

1. In the left navigation panel, choose Payment Configuration > Secure Acceptance Settings.
2. Click the menu on a profile and choose edit profile.
3. Click on the Notifications tab.
4. Enter your merchant notification POST URL (Must use HTTPS), Cybersource sends transaction information to this URL.
5. Click Save

Read more in the [Secure Acceptance checkout API integration guide](https://developer.cybersource.com/library/documentation/dev_guides/Secure_Acceptance_Checkout_API/Secure_Acceptance_Checkout_API.pdf)